# MongoTemplate multiple criteria query not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have a data in my db which looks like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ea75be37b8146000438b958"
    },
    "sourceBranch": "develop",
    "targetBranch": "master",
    "gitRepoId": "gitRepo",
    "jobName": "CIOrg",
    "createdBy": "Test@gmail.com",
    "connect2DeployUserEmail": "Test@gmail.com",
    "orgUserEmail": "Test@Test.com",
    "status": "notStarted",
    "startTimeRun": {
        "$date": "2020-04-27T22:30:00.000Z"
    },
    "executed": false,
    "boolActive": true,
    "_class": "com.backgroundworker.quartzJob.ScheduledDeploymentJob"
}
```

And Criteria query like below:

```
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(
            new Criteria().andOperator(
                    Criteria.where("startTimeRun").gte(from).lte(to),
                    Criteria.where("boolActive").is(boolActive),
                    Criteria.where("executed").is(executed)
            )
    );
```

And I am passing from and to in UTC format like this :

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
Date toDate = dateTime.plusSeconds(10).toLocalDateTime().toDate();
Date fromDate = dateTime.minusSeconds(10).toLocalDateTime().toDate();
```

But still the query did not pickup the data in db when the timeframe was inbetween the specified time? 
Am I missing anything , or is the query wrong?

Comment: Try turning up the log verbosity, or enable database profiling so you can see the exact query that the database server received.

Comment: Yeah figured out that date gets saved in UTC format in mongoDB, so I needed to pass DateTime object directly.

`DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC); DateTime toDate = dateTime.plusSeconds(10); DateTime fromDate = dateTime.minusSeconds(10);`, after passing date in Joda DateTime format it worked.